# .htaccess excluding rewrite css and images

Tags: php, css, image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some problems with rewriting URL-s

my .htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bsc/
RewriteRule ^(.+/?)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

my file and folder structure:

```
bsc/
---|.htaccess
---|index.php
---|css/
-------|style.css
---|images/
----------|logo.png
----------|image1.jpg
----------|image2.jpg
---|controller/
--------------|bootstrap.php
...
```

When I have next link

```
localhost/bsc/page.html
```

Than my css work or I can get to work. 
But when I have next links:

```
localhost/bsc/page/subpage.html
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/subsubpage.html
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/subsubpage/subsubsubpage.html
```

I can't get css to work, css is redirected to

```
localhost/bsc/page/css/style.css
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/css/style.css
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/subsubpage/css/style.css
```

Second part of problem is that my links don't have same extensions or any extension. 
Next situations are possible:

```
localhost/bsc/page/subpage
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/
localhost/bsc/page/subpage.php
localhost/bsc/page/subpage.html
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/subsubpage
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/subsubpage/
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/subsubpage.php
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/subsubpage.html
...
```

Now defined rewrite rule is working for different links but how to add excluded rule for css and images?

---

I get next .htaccess that work for css for all my conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bsc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.css
RewriteRule ^(.+/?)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

---

After reading comments and some time I get next .htaccess file with not so bad results:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bsc/
RewriteRule ^(.+/?)?(/|\.htm|\.php|\.html|/[^.]*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

and my link tag is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bsc/css/style.css" />
```

Now it is only one condition in URL when I can't get correct URL request. Next URL don't receive last parameter:

```
localhost/bsc/page/subpage
localhost/bsc/page/subpage/subsubpage
```

I don't receive *subpage* or *subsubpage*, other conditions are working. In this situation apache and .htaccess tray to find file or folders ....

Is it possible to add missing condition or is it possible to make some simplest rewrite rule or more rules

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably just need to use an absolute url for you css,

i.e.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Putting a slash infront forces it to the "root" of the url, thus making it consistent throughout subpages.

Comment: @MiroslavGojic glad to hear :) I see you just joined, if you could choose the answer as the right answer, we can get this question closed :).. Just to be proper..

Comment: Now is 95% solutions done and I must wait 8 hours to put my answer to me, There will be new .htaccess and one missing condition.

Comment: this is unrelated answer because htaccess is totaly apache related but this code is browser related just making a simple url request cannot effect on .htaccess rules

Comment: @VipanKumar actually, his question didn't specify htaccess specifically, but it was what he thought to be the cause of the problem. "I can't get css to work", was his problem, and my code provided a solution hence making it the right answer...

Answer (score 4):

I applied url rewriting to a project in core php. I faced the same problem. css, Js and images were not getting loaded. I used this and it worked for me. [Source](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/7500/best-way-to-modify-example-htaccess-to-allow-js-css-png-in-views/p1)

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before your rewriterule.
2. You should include css with `src="/css/style.css"` and NOT `src="css/style.css"` (note the missing starting `/`.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f, I tray to avoid this

Comment: If I'n not wrong %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f will allow direct access to all files on other words - it will not rewrite request if file existing in path request. But changing condition !-f with !\.css will explicitly allow CSS files and I can make my exceptions adding more conditions for images or some other document files.

Comment: I ussually only have javascript / css / image / other media files in the doc root, any file that shouldn't have direct access... simply is outside the doc root, to not directly accessible. That way this statement just works without a problem.

Comment: I'm familiar with the method that files are outside of doc root, but  currently I working on localhost in development phase. Of course later, when I finish I will relocate my files from doc root.